# IPtables DNAT with linux bridges (no interface addresses)

Tags: debian, iptables, bridge, nat

I've been doing some experimenting with iptables and bridges, and this scenario is just in a lab, but I've encountered some interesting functionality and would like some explanation as to what is happening (as it doesnt make sense when compared to the iptables flowcharts).

I have 3 interfaces on a Debian 11 server vm. ens3 is connected to the "internet" (lab external), ens4 is connected to the lab router, and ens5 is addressed and connected to a subnet inside the lab. ens3 and ens4 have no IP address.

I have created a bridge, br0, which contains the interfaces ens3 and ens4. This works perfectly fine, traffic coming from the "internet" or the lab router is moved properly between ens3 and ens4.

I have enabled br_netfilter kernel module, and enabled `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1` in an attempt to make bridged traffic seen by iptables.

The goal I have set for myself is to grab packets coming from the "internet" that match a certain port (22, SSH) and change the destination IP address to the IP of ens5.

If I add a blank rule (just to see the counters incrementing), `iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING`, then the pkt counter starts incrementing. So the traffic is seen at the `raw PREROUTING` chain.

If I add another blank rule, `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING`, then the pkt counter again starts incrementing. So the traffic is following the flowchart so far.

Heres where it gets interesting. If I add another blank rule to `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING` suddenly the pkt counter does NOT increment. But the flowchart states that traffic will flow from `mangle PREROUTING` to `nat PREROUTING`. But this clearly isn't happening.
Is there any flowcharts for how linux bridges interact with iptables chains? I am confused as to how/where the traffic is disappearing/going to.

I already have a rule written up for a DNAT rule, but I can only place that DNAT rule into `nat PREROUTING`, and if traffic is never seen by `nat PREROUTING`, then I cannot rewrite the destination IP. Unless there is a way to do DNAT in raw or mangle, but I am unaware of those methods.

Comment: flowchart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg check the sentence " "nat" table only consulted for "NEW" connections", then the bridge traffic part with iptables is the lower part of the schematic: the green boxes in blue field part rather than the green boxes in the green field.

Comment: What I am seeing in the counters it that the bridge traffic hits mangle prerouting. The mangle and nat are "connected" directly to each other. So that sentence saying only new connections for nat, is there a hidden check between mangle and nat prerouting that isn't shown in the diagram? And if there is a check, wouldn't my goal of dnat'ing port 22 count as a new connection anyways?